# String list from Arduino to Python array

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, numpy, matplotlib

I am reading in information via serial being sent by an Arduino. This is some example data being read:

```
4
1
5
2
15
1
```

Being a previous MATLAB user, I would just be able to copy the values and so something like

```
a = PASTE
```

to get a vector of the values. Is there a similar way to getting all the values in an int array or a matrix in the python terminal (using numpy and matplotlib for further plotting)?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please elaborate on `a = PASTE`?

Comment: Sorry. I meant I could just copy the data (as shown) into MATLAB such as "a = PASTECOMMAND". That, of course in MATLAB, would make a vector a consisting of the data.

Comment: I would think you would have to type `a = [` then paste then type `]` and then press enter? So I'm sure you can do that in Python too? What Python IDE are you using?

Comment: I tried a = [ PASTE ] before posting this question, didn't work.

I'm just using the Mac terminal.

Comment: I don't know about Mac, but if you're used to Matlab you should take a look at the Spyder IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, this works in Matlab because spaces are used to separate items in a sequence, and Matlab will let you use newlines instead of spaces.  In other words, you can do `x = [1 2 3]`

In python, commas are used instead.  In other words, you need to do `x = [1, 2, 3]`.

Python will let you have newlines in an expression if you've opened a brace/bracket, etc. For example, you can do:

```
In [1]: x = [1,
   ...: 2,
   ...: 3,
   ...: 4]

In [2]: x
Out[2]: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

...but you still need the commas for it to be valid syntax.

If you want to use newlines as a seperator for the sequence (that you've presumably copied to the clipboard), you'll need to explicitly split the string on newlines.

To start a multi-line string, use triple-quotes. (`"""` or `'''`)

For example: (I've typed `x = """` and then hit paste (e.g. `<ctrl>-v`/`<shift>-<ins>`/whatever))

```
In [1]: x = """4
   ...: 1
   ...: 5
   ...: 2
   ...: 15
   ...: 1"""

In [2]: x
Out[2]: '4\n1\n5\n2\n15\n1'

In [3]: x.split()
Out[3]: ['4', '1', '5', '2', '15', '1']

In [4]: import numpy as np

In [5]: np.array(x.split(), dtype=float)
Out[5]: array([  4.,   1.,   5.,   2.,  15.,   1.])
```

Also, as @HYRY mentioned, if you're using `ipython`, it will do the equivalent of

```
In [1]: x = """4
   ...: 1
   ...: 5
   ...: 2
   ...: 15
   ...: 1"""

In [2]: x = x.split()
```

With just:

```
In [1]: %paste x
```

Better yet, if you're reading data in from the serial port, just read it directly into python.  Have a look at `pyserial`: http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 3):

If you use IPython, you can :

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> %paste x
>>> x = np.array(x, int)
```

Comment: Tried it, but getting this error: ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: 'import numpy as np'

Comment: You need copy the data to the clipboard and input '%paste x' in ipython console.